# macOS stuck in recovery mode and can’t reinstall

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

When I try to reinstall it says like that and I cant erase my disk as well

[image]

Comment: How did you initiate the reinstall? Do you need Sierra? Can you go to High Sierra?

Comment: **Why** can't you erase the disk?  What happens when you try?